# Control a pop-up window status

Tags: javascript, window

IS there a way in Javascript to control the status of an open pop-up window?

I open the pop-up window with javascript and I need to close it at a certain point, specifically when the URL of that pop-up window contains these parameters:

```
oauth_token
```

and

```
oauth_verifier
```

ie: `http://mysite.com.com/dev/uspolitics_pulse/functions.php?oauth_token=XX184mmCiV1Vp5EXNAdswiwrOUrZBkGx7bAdE0UwCTU&oauth_verifier=rIJJPdAPFzXQFsNvZufdSKTZdImGxSgyN7xKgNZz644`

Comment: Is the page reloaded when these tokens/values are added to the URL, or is this via some kind of Ajax mechanism?

Comment: Is this for the landing page on your site after an oauth process is over?  If so, you could have a go between page that uses those variables as your system needs, then redirect to the actual landing page without the vars in the url?  Masking the status bar would only fool some anyways...

Answer (score 0):

The function `open` returns the window object of the pop-up window.

That object has a method called `close` that can be used to close the pop-up window. It has the same properties as the global window object like `location` that can be used to get the URL.